# Autocomplete select value

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I need your help to solve a problem with jquery autocomplete. I've include jquery v1.11 and i've create this script.

For the html page:

```
    <input id="box_contributors_adduser_input_search" type="search" maxlength="25" placeholder="Nome Utente"/>
    <div id='contributors_adduser_autocomplete_div'>
      <ul class='contributors_adduser_autocomplete_ul'></ul></div>
    </div>
```

and this for js part:

```
$(function()  {
  $("#box_contributors_adduser_input_search").autocomplete({

    source: "user.php",
    select: function(event, ui) {
      alert(ui.item.value);
    },
    search: function(event, ui) {
      $('.contributors_adduser_autocomplete_ul').empty();
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
      $('.contributors_adduser_autocomplete_ul').empty();
      $("#contributors_adduser_autocomplete_div").css("display", "none");
    }
  })
  .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

    if($('#contributors_adduser_autocomplete_div').css('display') == 'none')
     {$("#contributors_adduser_autocomplete_div").css("display", "block");}

    return $("<li></li>")
    .data('ui-autocomplete-item', item)
    .append("<p>"+item.label+"</p><p>"+item.desc+"</p>")
    .appendTo($('.contributors_adduser_autocomplete_ul'));
  };
});
```

i've two type of problems, first the event select doesn't work, if i click on item nothing happens.

The second problems is an error that start when i scroll the list of item with keyboard, the error log return me this error in jquery-ui file:

```
    item = ui.item.data( "ui-autocomplete-item" );
    if ( false !== this._trigger( "focus", event, { item: item } ) ) {
        // use value to match what will end up in the input, if it was a key event
        if ( event.originalEvent && /^key/.test( event.originalEvent.type ) ) {
            this._value( item.value );
        }
    }
```

the line this.value is not define. :(

Can anyone help me to solve? Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Did you include jQuery-UI as well as jQuery? `.autocomplete` is a -UI method.

Comment: yes, the error i receive is in the jquery ui page